# OR Constraints in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to add an or constraint in PuLP to choose between two cases. In short, I have a set of binary variables that I want all to be 1 or 0 at once. I'm trying to solve a scheduling problem and I have a list of hours for the day, I want to loop over the hours of the day for 4 variables and ensure that at every hour, each of the four variables is either 1 or 0. Below is the pseudocode I want to write.

for j in day:

x[1,j]+x[2,j]+x[3,j]+x[4,j]=4 OR x[1,j]+x[2,j]+x[3,j]+x[4,j]=0

I can easily add one of the constraints by doing:

```
for j in day: 
    tmpExpression = LpAffineExpression(e = [(x[i,j], 1) for i in [1,2,3,4]])
    tmpConstraint = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tmpExpression),
    sense = LpConstraintEQ,                                
        rhs = 4)
    model.addConstraint(tmpConstraint)
```

But I'm not knowing how to add the or condition to force it to select either rhs=4 or 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is really very simple.

```
 x[1,j]+x[2,j]+x[3,j]+x[4,j]=4 OR x[1,j]+x[2,j]+x[3,j]+x[4,j]=0

    <=>

 x[1,j]+x[2,j]+x[3,j]+x[4,j]=4*y[j]
 y[j] ∈ {0,1}
```

Of course, even better is to replace `x[1,j],x[2,j],x[3,j],x[4,j]` by just a single variable. They are indistinguishable.